# Como manter a posição do scroll dentro de uma div após atualizar dinamicamente com AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Estou construindo um mini fórum, e nele, os usuários podem fazer *posts* e respondê-los.

Para a página não ficar muito longa, eu coloquei uma `div` com uma altura e largura fixas, e, se o texto passar desse valor, ele irá acrescentar uma barra de rolagem,

### O problema é:

Eu utilizo o ***AJAX*** para atualizar as respostas de tempos em tempos, e sempre que eu atualizo,e ele volta a barra de rolagem para a posição inicial, queria saber se tem como eu pegar a posição atual da barra de rolagem dentro da `div`, e quando atualizar com o ***ajax***, ele voltar a barra nessa posição.

Esse é o código do `AJAX`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    comeca();
})
var timerR = false;
var timerI = null;
function para(){
    if(timerR)
        clearTimeout(timerI)
    timerR = false;

}
function comeca(){
    para();
    lista();
}
function lista(){
 $.ajax({
        url:"qrTopico.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {topico : "<?php echo $topicoGet; ?>"},
        success: function (textStatus){
              $('#respostas').html(textStatus); //mostrando resultado
        }
    })
    timerI = setTimeout("lista()", 10000);//tempo de espera
    timerR = true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como não posso comentar, vou deduzir que você está destruindo os elementos e populando novamente de acordo com o que você retorna em sua requisição Ajax, caso esteja fazendo isso, esse comportamento de a barra ir para o topo é de se esperar.

Sugiro que você faça um incremento dos dados que estão sendo atualizados nos elementos que já estão criados, assim a barra de rolagem ira manter sua posição atual.

Comment: Faz sentido... Mas teria como você postar algum código ou me direcionar pra algum tópico que me ajude com isso?

Comment: Para eu postar algum código, preciso pelo menos do seu código de requisição do Ajax e ver a melhor maneira de fazer o incremento das informações.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve gravar o conteudo de `window.scrollTop` em uma variavel antes de abrir o campo de edição e após salvar ou recarregar algo com ajax, também pode-se usar via jQuery (já que usou a tag [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery))

Ficaria algo como:

```
function atualizaScroll(lastScrollY)
{
    $('#respostas').scrollTop(lastScrollY);
}

function atualizarDados()
{
    var lastScrollY = $('#respostas').scrollTop();

    $.ajax("pagina.php", {
        ... //Dados da requisição aqui
    }).done(function () {
       //Completa a requisição
    }).fail(function () {
       //mostra erro
    }).complete(function () {
       /*
        * Executa mesmo com erro ou sucesso
        * (restaura posição do scroll)
        *
        * Delay é para evitar algo com o tempo da renderização
        */

       setTimeout(atualizaScroll, 10, lastScrollY);
    });
}
```

Comment: Eu testei o código acima, mas aparentemente ele funcionaria bem se fosse o scroll "global" da página, no meu caso, eu precisaria que esse comportamento acontecesse com o scroll dentro de uma Div. Como eu faria isso?

Comment: @kyro23 a sim entendi, falha minha, vou editar :)

Comment: @kyro23 corrigi o código e corrigi o setTimeout também, me avisa se falhar ;)

Comment: @kyro23 ué, o exemplo não funcionou? Você não deu retorno

Comment: Então, eu não dei retorno porquê passei um boom tempo procurando a solução para esse problema, e pelo que eu entendi, é um pouco mais complexo que só o scroll da div... Basicamente eu vou ter que fazer long pooling para manter uma conexão aberta com o servidor, e verificar se o resultado mudou, ai sim, quando ele mudar, eu exibo a nova informação na tela. O problema é que como eu quero fazer o site rodar em um servidor, eu vou ter que usar web sockets pra fazer essa conexão, então eu ainda to estudando qual seria a melhor solução. Mas valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: @kyro23 mas long pooling ou ajax são apenas maneiras de obter os dados, o problema é no front-end, não tem haver com a origem, me diz você quer recuperar a posição do scroll ou você quer forçar o scroll sempre ficar na posição da mensagem mais recente, igual aos chats/bate-papos online?

Comment: Bom, basicamente é o seguinte:
Da forma que eu fiz, o AJAX vai fazer uma requisição ao servidor a cada 10 segundos, e quando ele terminar essa requisição, ele mostra todas as informações na tela, e quando atualizar, isso acontece denovo e denovo. Mas seria muito mais fácil se ele só atualizar quando houver uma informação nova no banco de dados. É ai que entraria o webSockets, pois, imagina um servidor com mil usuários ao mesmo tempo recebendo informações de cada usuário a cada 10 segundos, obviamente o server vai cair. E eu também tenho planos de fazer  outros sistemas semelhantes no site.

Comment: @kyro23 tudo bem eu entendo, mas ainda sim isto não tem haver com a duvida e se você colocar que o problema é "qual o melhor caminho de comunicar front-end com back-end" você vai mudar o sentido da pergunta. Entenda que não somos um fórum e sim um Q&A, a pergunta deve ser objetiva, edita-la e mudar o assunto invalidaria as respostas ao meu ver....

Comment: ... Outra coisa **independente** de como obtém os dados a solução que eu mostrei é para resolver algo com o scroll e deve funcionar em qualquer situação, agora a duvida que mais importa: você quer recuperar a posição do scroll ou você quer forçar o scroll sempre ficar na posição da mensagem mais recente, igual aos chats/bate-papos online? @kyro23

Comment: Eu entendo que o correto seria eu abrir uma nova pergunta, pois a questão aqui é sobre o scroll e não sobre webSockets, porquê o meu problema inicial era só o scroll, mas eu acabei percebendo que não era SÓ o scroll... Pra você ter uma idéia do que eu to falando, esse é o site que eu estou desenvolvendo: http://indieworld.atwebpages.com/topico.php?t=VkZaRk9WQlJQVDA9 , e como pode perceber, se você mexer no scroll dentro da div, ele volta pra posição inicial, justamente porquê ele está atualizando essa div, onde o certo seria somente incrementar uma nova div.

Comment: E respondendo a sua pergunta, o comportamento do scroll que eu desejo é que ele mantenha-se na mesma posição que o usuário deixou.

Comment: @kyro23 então acho que a resposta aqui funciona perfeitamente sendo ajax ou webscoket, deve ter falhado porque você colocou na ordem errada algum evento. Notei que no site ainda esta o script antigo

Comment: Sim, a ideia é que a div tenha uma altura fixa e quando essa altura estourar ele criar o scroll

Comment: @kyro23 **achei o problema**, você usou vários IDs repetidos, o atributo ID não pode ser repetido. Você repetiu id=resposta e id=respostas algumas vezes, ID deve ser unico sempre

Comment: O código atualizado ainda ta no localhost, mas mesmo alterando de id para class o resultado continua sendo o mesmo

Comment: @kyro23 mas não basta alterar uma coisinha ou outra, deve ser uma falha sua, desculpe mas só estou querendo lhe orientar para o real problema, estou apenas tentando ajudar, não é uma critica negativa ;)

Comment: Sim, eu entendo, mas a solução mais lógica é mudar essa forma de atualização dinâmica, porquê pro que eu planejo fazer iria requisitar muito do servidor (que ainda é um plano gratuito de testes), além de que eu pretendo implementar a mesma tecnologia em outras funções, como um chat e um sistema de notificações, ou seja, essa maneira de atualizar a página não se encaixa na demanda que eu preciso. Mas mesmo assim, obrigado por me ajudar :D